# Linq GroupBy with sort, take first, and return a list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm stuck on a Linq-to-SQL query. I have a table of items, with multiple items per user. I want to get the list of all the latest items per user. This is what I have:

```
var TheList = (from t in MyDataContext.TheTable
               where t.SomeDate > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-3)

               group t by t.UserID into TheUserGroups
               from g in TheGroups
               orderby g.SomeDate descending

               select new SomeObject()
               {
                     TheUserID = g.UserID,
                     .....
                }).ToList();
```

The problem is that it's returning all the items of every user instead of the most recent element per user. What do I need to change to get the expected result?

Comment: LINQ To SQL? Are you sure you are not using Entity Framework? You are really using .NET 3.5 in 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
var TheList = (from t in MyDataContext.TheTable
               where t.SomeDate > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-3)

               orderby g.SomeDate descending

               select new SomeObject()
               {
                     TheUserID = g.UserID,
                })
                .GroupBy(x => x.TheUserID)
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: It doesn't like the .SelectMany() operation

Comment: The use Select instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }

    table.Where(o => o.Date < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-3))
                    .GroupBy(o => o.UserId)
                    .Select(g => new { UserId = g.Key, LastOrder = g.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).FirstOrDefault() })
.ToList();
```